# Is transient fault handling necessary with Azure SQL Database Premium Service Tier?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I know on the basic / standard tiers it is recommended, was just wondering if the premium service tier offer a superior service which negates the need for transient fault handling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would there be? No matter the tier you are still making calls where temporary conditions such as intermittent service, infrastructure-level faults, or network issues may occur. This is not exclusively a problem with SQL Azure. If you use Cache, Storage, Service Bus or any other service you are still subjected to this scenario.

More info:

[Transient Fault Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680901(v=pandp.50).aspx)

Comment: Some more useful articles http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-connectivity-issues/

Answer (score 0):

No the selection of service tier doesn't change anything from transient fault handling side.